# Cloudflare cache causes "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to not be sent

Tags: caching, heroku, http-headers, cloudflare

A node JS express app hosted on heroku and configured with cloudflare is displaying a strange behaviour : it works for a couple requests and then fails with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Purging everything in the cloudflare cache allows the app to work again... until the urls are stored in the cache.

I would like to either allow cached queries to send the headers, or disable caching

Answer (score 2):

If those URLs have a pattern, you can set a Page Rule in CloudFlare to never cache those URLs. Got a live URL we can take a look at?

Comment: turns out it was just a bad Express configuration. Thanks!

Comment: can you share what was the bad express config? @MisterFresh